# IntelliJ IDEA java directory paths problem

Tags: java, intellij-idea, path

I have a problem with paths. I've got a test project like this below and I want to create a JSON reader in Main so I need a test_json path. I don't wanna use an absolute path D:..., but a path "from project" (I mean smth like main://resources/json_test/test_json.json). Is there any way to do that?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7DPy.png)

Comment: If it's in src/resources load it as a classpath resource, not as a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is in your resources folder, use getResource.

If calling from a non-static method:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/json_test/test_json.json");
```

If calling from a static method:

```
<ClassName>.class.getClassLoader.getResource("/json_test/test_json.json");
```

The `getResource()` method will look for the path inside the src/main/resources folder, so your path should include any subdirectories you might have created inside the resources folder for the file.